# "Error: Transition-group inside component is not supported" using Element UI and Vue Draggable

Tags: sortablejs, vuejs-transition

I'm using element ui's [collapse](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/collapse) along with [vuedraggable](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable).
And I'm trying to implement vue transition-group to the collapsible items. The vuedraggable documentation says that you can simply do it this way:

```
 <draggable v-model="myArray">
    <transition-group>
        <div v-for="element in myArray" :key="element.id">
            {{element.name}}
        </div>
    </transition-group>
</draggable>
```

In my case, I'm putting the draggable items in an "el-menu" component. This is why I'm getting an error:

"Error: Transition-group inside component is not supported"

This is what I got so far:

```
<draggable element="el-menu" :list="branch.list" :component-data="getComponentData()">
    <transition-group>
        <el-menu-item
        v-for="(list, list_key) in branch.list" 
        :index="list_key+ '_list'"
        :key="leaf_key + '_list'">
            content
        </el-menu-item>
    </transition-group>
</draggable>
```

Comment: Following this tutorial maybe fix your problem. https://deepscan.io/docs/rules/vue-bad-transition-group